# Can I use pycript to get the contents of a webiste and access it in javascript without same origin?

Tags: javascript, pyscript

I dont really know python that well, but I was able to scrounge up a script that hits a website and downloads the data from it, saving that data to a file. I used python over javascript because fetch is limited by cors same origin and python is not. I also didnt want to set up a proxy server. I added a file input field on my site for people to upload what the python script saves. Then I remembered pyscript was a thing. I tried running my python script in pyscript but got errors about the imports... I have no clue what I am doing here. If anyone has some advice.

Here is the python script:

```py
import sys
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Declare variables
review_limit = 15
comment_limit = 4

# Get the list of id numbers from the command line arguments
ids = sys.argv[1:]

# If no id numbers are provided, ask the user to enter them
if not ids:
    ids = input("Enter the id numbers separated by a space: ").split()

# Initialize the data object
data = {}

for id in ids:
    # Make sure it's a valid number
    if id and int(id) > 0:
        url_model = f"https://example.com/{id}/{review_limit}/{comment_limit}/"

        # Send a GET request to the page and parse the response
        response = requests.get(url_model)
        doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        # Extract the data from the response
        page_data = doc.find(id="jsonDiv").text

        # Parse the data text as JSON
        page_data = json.loads(page_data)

        # Add the data to the data object
        data[id] = {
            "pageData": page_data
        }

# Write the data object to a file, pretty-printing the JSON data
with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2)
```

The idea would be that the user is asked for ids and for each id it gets the data from the website. That data is then added to a JSON object that has the data of all the ids and then sent back to Javascript to be processed further.

Comment: No code running in a browser can circumvent the SOP, or else it would be a security hole in the browser. Doesn't matter whether it's JavaScript or PyScript. "*javascript is limited and python is not*" is the wrong way to look at it.

Comment: "*got errors about the imports*" - **which** errors?

Comment: Also, you cannot use Python packages such as **requests**. The browser does not support many common Python features/packages because everything runs within a secure virtual machine. I wrote a bunch of articles about PyScript on my website. Start with some of my articles, or other guides, to learn the basics.